# How to make Wordpress show only one post on the front page with comments, and comment form?

Tags: wordpress, post, comments

I did the following to display a single post in my home page:

**home.php:**

```
<?php
get_header();
query_posts('posts_per_page=1'); //returns only the front page
?>

<div id="content">
    <?php
    /* Run the loop to output the posts.
     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
     * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.
     */
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
    ?>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But I still ahave to click `Comments` in order to see the comments and the form to leave a comment. How can I automatically show immediately?

Answer (score 1):

Load the comments template using `<?php comments_template(); ?>` - that'll display all comments for the current post.

Comment: Sorry, I placed that code right before the #content div and nothing happened!

Comment: If you want to show comments before you load the loop, call `the_post()`, load your comments, then reset the loop with `rewind_posts()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="blog">
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="blog-sidebar">
                        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span8">
                    <?php $articles = new WP_Query(array(
                                        'post_type' => 'post',
                                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                                        'posts_per_page' => 1
                                    ));?>
                        <?php  while ($articles->have_posts()): $articles->the_post(); ?>
                            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="article">
                                <header>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?></a> 
                                <section class="post_content clearfix" >
                                     <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </section> 
                            </article>
                        <?php endwhile; ?> 
                      <?php comments_template('',true); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```