# Custom Homepage with 1 blog post only

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to set a blog as homepage. I created  a front-page.php with the code below.

The code shows the recent post as homepage. I want to use 1 specific blog as homepage instead of the recent blogs or sticky posts.

Here's the sample site. The blog is used as homepage. The homepage doesn't change if new blogs are published.

https://height-comparison.com/

Original post:
[How to make Wordpress show only one post on the front page with comments, and comment form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193493/how-to-make-wordpress-show-only-one-post-on-the-front-page-with-comments-and-co/68665678#68665678)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="blog">
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="blog-sidebar">
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                <?php $articles = new WP_Query(array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 1
                                ));?>
                    <?php  while ($articles->have_posts()): $articles->the_post(); ?>
                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="article">
                            <header>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?></a> 
                            <section class="post_content clearfix" >
                                 <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </section> 
                        </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?> 
                  <?php comments_template('',true); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're asking. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

you can use sticky posts
example [wpbeginner sticky posts](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-the-latest-sticky-posts-in-wordpress/)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="blog">
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="blog-sidebar">
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                <?php 

                /* Get all sticky posts */
                $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
                 
                /* Sort the stickies with the newest ones at the top */
                rsort( $sticky );
                 
                /* Get the 5 newest stickies (change 5 for a different number) */
                $sticky = array_slice( $sticky, 0, 5 );
                 
                /* Query sticky posts */



                $articles = new WP_Query(array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                                    'post__in' => $sticky,
                                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                                    'posts_per_page' => 1
                                ));?>
                    <?php  while ($articles->have_posts()): $articles->the_post(); ?>
                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="article">
                            <header>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'wpbs-featured' ); ?></a> 
                            <section class="post_content clearfix" >
                                 <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </section> 
                        </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?> 
                  <?php comments_template('',true); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I am trying to achieve this https://height-comparison.com/. The blog is set as homepage and It doesn't change if new blogs are published.